# Get directory above CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR in CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake

`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` returns the directory where the currently processed CMakeLists.txt is located in. The path is a full path from root.

How can we access, say a directory above the `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`.

E.g. If `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/saurabhshri/Documents/GitHub/repo/src/`

And I want the path `/Users/saurabhshri/Documents/GitHub/repo/`.

Of course doing `../${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` gives `..//Users/saurabhshri/Documents/GitHub/repo/src/`.

I looked into "Locations" documentation of CMake (https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Locations) and can not find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it done using `get_filename_component`.

```
get_filename_component(DIR_ONE_ABOVE ../ ABSOLUTE)
message(STATUS ${DIR_ONE_ABOVE})
```

Complete documentation : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html

Thanks to *ngladitz* from the cmake IRC channel.

Answer (score 1):

In CMake 3.20 and greater, you can get the parent path using the [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html) command, which supersedes the `get_filename_component` command:

> ```
> cmake_path(GET <path-var> PARENT_PATH <out-var>)
> ```

So, in your case, you could use this:

```
cmake_path(GET CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR PARENT_PATH MY_PARENT_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to like

> E.g. If CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = >/Users/saurabhshri/Documents/GitHub/repo/src/
> And I want the path /Users/saurabhshri/Documents/GitHub/repo/.

More easier way than above answers

`${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}../`

Comment: it does not work for me.